# What does parenthesis BEFORE register mean in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, windbg, disassembly, ida

While debugging an application with IDA Pro and WinDbg, I came across following statement.

```
mov esi, ds:(dword_16C6 - 16B2h)[esi]
```

To simplify, let's say

```
mov esi, ds:(ABC)[esi]
```

What does `(ABC)` mean here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Intel syntax, round parenthesis are for grouping, just like in mathematics.  This, is done because

```
ds:dword_16C6 - 16B2h[esi]
```

might be interpreted as

```
(ds:dword_16C6) - (16B2h[esi])
```

which doesn't make any sense.

In AT&T syntax, square brackets are used for grouping instead.

---

In other words, it's a complex way of writing `ds:[esi + dword_16C6 - 16B2h]`, or `ds:dword_16C6[esi - 16B2h]` which are both also valid MASM syntax (I think).

Some might say unnecessarily complex, but it does give consistency with `symbol[index]` syntax which this disassembler uses for symbol + register(s) addressing modes.

Comment: so... it's just a complicated way to write `ds:[esi + dword_16C6 - 16B2h]`, which I thnk is valid MASM syntax.

Comment: I do think so, yes.

Comment: Okey, `8(%ebp)` is familiar to me. Then this is similar. Thanks